# AWS managing users via Cognito

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have used many services from AWS, some were easy, while some were a bit difficult. After 2 days of searching everywhere, I can say documentation for this service is misleading.

I have simple task to do. I want to change a user attribute in the Cognito pool. And to make things easy, I just need to change an Email, and thats it. Application is an Backoffice (Express/Node), where admins can change user's email.

After reading and reading, I am getting more confused. Apparently, the `aws-sdk` library, the one I am familiar with, has some Cognito API's that I could use. Getting a working example on how to use them, turned out to be a nightmare.
Then I found out there is a [library](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js), but only to be used on the client side. After some tweaks I got it running in Node.js. The tweak was to expose a `fetch` library in global Node.js namespace.

I was able to add a new user. But for all my intentions, I can't change any of the attributes (like email). The library wants me to provide Username (real user) and a password.
I do have a Username (in this case an email), but I don't have the password.

All I need to do is to connect to the service, and send new attribute for the user and thats it.
This is what I have so far (mainly hacked code samples, from variety of places), and I cant get it to work:

```
var poolData = {
    UserPoolId : 'euXXXXXXX',
    ClientId : 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
};
var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
```

Ok The above line makes a connection to the existing user pool.

Now if I were to do this:

```
var attributeList = [];

var dataEmail = {
    Name : 'email',
    Value : 'email@mydomain.com'
};

var dataPhoneNumber = {
    Name : 'phone_number',
    Value : '+15555555555'
};

var attributeEmail = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(dataEmail);
var attributePhoneNumber = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(dataPhoneNumber);

attributeList.push(attributeEmail);
attributeList.push(attributePhoneNumber);

userPool.signUp('username', 'password', attributeList, null, function(err, result){
    if (err) {
        alert(err.message || JSON.stringify(err));
        return;
    }
    cognitoUser = result.user;
    console.log('user name is ' + cognitoUser.getUsername());
});
```

I can see in AWS console that the user is being added. Great.

Now how to change the attributes of the existing user?
All of examples like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js) and [this](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js)
Suggest the following:

> Use case 8. Update user attributes for an authenticated user.

```
var attributeList = [];
var attribute = {
    Name : 'nickname',
    Value : 'joe'
};
var attribute = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(attribute);
attributeList.push(attribute);

cognitoUser.updateAttributes(attributeList, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        alert(err.message || JSON.stringify(err));
        return;
    }
    console.log('call result: ' + result);
});
```

The problem here is I cant authenticate the user. I can't know user's password, only his email. This is after all a simple Backoffice program, where I just need to change users email.

What can I do in this case?

Comment: You should use the `aws-sdk` for this. [adminUpdateUserAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminUpdateUserAttributes-property)

Comment: I am getting AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminUpdateUserAttributes is not a function... do you have any idea?

Comment: I got it working :). Would you please make an answer and post it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update the attributes of a Cognito User Pool-user as an admin, you should use [adminUpdateUserAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminUpdateUserAttributes-property) function from the `aws-sdk` class `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider`.

```
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
let cognitoISP = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ region: 'your-region-here' });

function updateUserAttribute(name, value, username, userPoolId){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let params = {
            UserAttributes: [
                {
                    Name: name,     // name of attribute
                    Value: value    // the new attribute value
                }
            ],
            UserPoolId: userPoolId,
            Username: username
        };

        cognitoISP.adminUpdateUserAttributes(params, (err, data) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(data));
    });
}
```